# Attaching a resistor to a oscilliscope probe

Tags: oscilloscope

I'm doing some ultra low power electronics, and I need a probe with an impedance higher than 10Mohm. Is it alright to just attach a 90Mohm resistor to the end of my 10x probe to turn it into a 100x probe? The signals are all under 1Mhz. Are there any problems that could arise?

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative to doing this, you might want to consider making an active voltage follower using a low Ib op-amp.

Even an inexpensive TL071 will have something like 1T ohm input resistance and input capacitance of  if you stay inside the input voltage range (eg. give it something like +/-10V supplies and stay within +/-8V. Bias current is under 100pA typically at room temperature so 10M ohm source resistance will contribute negligible error (in comparison to the offset voltage). There are much lower Ib op-amps available (down to fA).

Answer (score 4):

New resistor and old capacitance make a lowpass filter. The pulses get rounded due hf attenuation. You should add also a small capacitor in parallel with the resistor.  Learn how normal probe compensation works.

You can still use oscilloscope's own square wave output for probe adjustments and checking the new scaling.

You also lose possible automatic probe type detection and automatic scaling. No obvious other problems.

Add the resistor as near as possible to the measured point. Do not try to insert it at the input of the oscilloscope. Otherwise the inserted resistor doesn't reduce the reactive loading of the measured signal.

Comment: Watch out for the parasitic DC leakage of the capacitor.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify a standard 10:1 passive 10 MOhm probe, you will run into bandwidth issue. Best (Keysight, Tektronix, etc) probes would have about 10 pF input impedance, 10^-11 F. With a 100M resistor (10^8 Ohms) this will form a RC filter at about 1ms (10^8 * 10^-11). Which is about 170 Hz at -3dB level.

A 1MHz probe with 100 MOhm impedance needs to be carefully designed, there is some literature on this. Keysight/Agilent has a 66 MOhm/3pF/500MHz probe, [model 10076C](https://www.keysight.com/en/pd-2477535-pn-10076C/1001-4-kv-500-mhz-high-voltage-probe?nid=-32557.1109153&cc=US&lc=eng). It is however 100:1, so signals have to be strong.